# if each string contains a specific substring equal true, how do I make it do nothing?

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, contains

I have a code that looks like this

```
df.loc[:,"col_1"].str.contains("125\/w+", regex= True)
```

and I get this

```
30        True
32       False
74        True
113       True
161      False
         ...  
45026    False
45042     True
45044     True
45051     True
45054    False
```

How to I make each variable that gave **True** to display as the original string

and

the each variable that **False** to turn blank (NaN)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `.where`:

`df['col_1'].where(df['col_1'].str.contains("125\/w+", regex=True))`

```
      col_1        
30     True
32      NaN
74     True
113    True
161     NaN
       ...
45026   NaN
45042  True
45044  True
45051  True
45054   NaN
```